# Spring Data JPAで分割されたテーブルにアクセスするベストプラクティスな実装方法が知りたい

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, database, jpa

例えば、ユーザー情報をもつuserテーブル
user_0, user_1, user_2, user_3（userIdを4で除算したときのあまりがテーブル名の後ろにつく）
に対してentityとrepositoryをテーブルの数だけ複数実装しなくても良い実装方法を知りたいです。

最悪の場合、service層で使用するrepositoryを動的に変更しようとはしてますが、同じようなentityとrepositoryを複数実装したくないです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: バックエンドのDBテーブルを`userId`でパーティショニングして扱うのが自然な状況に見えますが、それができない理由があるのでしょうか?

Comment: 返信遅くなりすいません。コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: すいません。コメントの途中でした。
確かにおっしゃる通りパーティショニングが自然かもしれません！しかし、テーブルが既に分割されていたため上記のような実装方法を模索しているところでした。

Answer (score 1):

DBからのアプローチですが、同じ構造のテーブルであれば、`UNION`したVIEWを用意する方法があると思います。つまり、以下のようなVIEW「`user`」を作れば、entityもrepositoryも1つで十分になると思います。

```
    CREATE VIEW user as (
    select * from user_0
    union
    select * from user_1
    union
    select * from user_2
    union
    select * from user_3
    );
```

Comment: 反応遅くなりすいません。SQLからのアプローチは全く想定していなかったので参考になります。ありがとうございます。